# why I can not use get request when use manyToOne relation in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab6f8.jpg)I newly start learning java spring and I faced a problem from 3 days and I can bot solve it .
I have two entities employ and department and the relations manytoone
The problem is when I add employees to the department then I make get request it doesn’t work and give me this message in the pic

Comment: Does this work normally? How does this problem relate to manyToOne, and what errors/messages do you see in the server side logs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.